# How do I use Extracted Legendary powers?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I've been building up my Extracted Legendary Powers library in Kanai's Cube, but at this point, I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to access them again.

I know I can select them, but that's as far as I have been able to get at this point; none of the options in the "recipes" have given me any inclination on how to access them.

How do I use the Extracted Legendary Powers in Kanai's Cube?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You select one of the three slots you want to add the power to. Then you select the item whose power you want to use. The item is then visible in the selected slot. Once its visible, the power is active.

[image]

This means you can have a total of 3 powers active. 1 weapon, 1 armor and 1 jewelry.

[image]

The easiest way to test the cube is following:

1. Open the cube
2. Select jewelry slot (ring)
3. Select "Convention of Elements"
4. Close the cube
5. Look at your buffs and see "Convention of Elements" active

Also, the selected items in the cube are tied to each armory set slot. So if you set up 2 armory sets with different cube items, there is no need to change the cube items manually if you change the equipment set via armory.

Comment: The second image is a bit small, so I can't quite make out what is going on there. Do I apply these powers to an item I have in my inventory? If so, how? Is there a specific button to press, recipe to use, or item quality required?

Comment: `Once its visible, the power is active`. Nothing to do besides selecting the item whose power you want. The second picture is just to show that you can have max 3 powers active.

Comment: Right, so I don't actually apply them to a weapon, or reforge the legendary weapon, I just get that buff applied to my PC?

Comment: You just select the item in the list like shown in the first picture. As soon as the item has the border, the buff is always active. There is no need to "lock" the selection. In the example of the first picture, the effect of "Burst of Wrath" is now active.

Comment: As a bonus knowledge that could be nice to know for you @Ben if you never used extracted bonus, these extracted bonuses always give the best the bonus can if it can vary in range.

Comment: I had never realised that's how it worked. A good example (which is what I used) was the Puzzle Ring. It spawns a treasure goblin that's filled you around. Once I applied this effect in Kanais Cube, the goblin appeared. Thanks!

Comment: The "Puzzle Ring" and the "Bovine Bardiche" have special effects if extracted without ingredients. Just place the item alone in the cube and press "Transform"